# Error ngOninit en Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo una pequeña duda, al añadir jquery a  Angular 10, me salta este error y lo he comprobado varias veces, cualquier ayuda me vendría bien. Dejo el código para más ayuda, un saludo.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOninit(): void{
    
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciudado con los 'caps', estás poniendo ngOninit() y debería de ser:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // ...
}
```

NOTA: el error no es por jquery como dices en el texto, de todas formas en los mensajes de error ya te lo está diciendo: propiedad 'ngOnInit' no se encuentra. Recuerda que las variables y los nombres de metedos y demás son 'key sensitive', es decir, que si son sensibles a las mayúsculas y minúsculas como es este caso.